# Compare rows of 2 pandas data frames by column and keep bigger and sum

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames of same IDs with identical structure:

```
X, Y, Value, ID
```

The only difference between the two should be values in column Value - it may need to be sorted by ID first so both have same order of rows to make sure.

I want to compare these two data frames by row based on column Value and keep the row from first or second depending where the Value is bigger. I would also like to see example how to add additional column SUM for sum of Value columns from both data frames.

I will be glad for any example, including using numpy if you feel it is better to use for this than Pandas.

**Edit:** I just realized after testing the example from the first answer that the data frames I have are missing completely the rows with ids where Value was null. That makes two data frames of different number of rows. So could be please also included how to make them same size before comparison - adding rows with missing ids from each other with IDs and zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2])
      .groupby(['ID','X','Y'])
      .agg({'value':'max', 'value_sum':'sum'}))
```

Comment: Not useful w/o explanation. E.g. what's `df1` and `df2`? Also I don't see the sorting the OP mentioned.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliantly simple and working exactly as I need. I was looking at concat and merge before but it didn't make sense to me because I completely did not realize there can be groupby function used. A bit of comments as suggested above would be good though.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

# create a new dataframe, where Value is the max value per row
val1 = df1['Value']
val2 = df2['Value'][val1.index]  # align to val1
df = df1.copy()
df['Value'] = np.maximum(val1, val2)

# add a SUM column:
df1['SUM'] = df1['Value'].sum()
df2['SUM'] = df2['Value'].sum()
```

Comment: I really like this approach and it works when the data frames are same size but unfortunately when testing this I realized my data frames are missing lines which had null Values.

Answer (score 2):

I use [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) for align dataframes and then [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filling column `Value` of new dataframe `df`:

```
print df1
   X  Y  Value  ID
0  1  4     10   0
1  2  5     55   1
2  3  6     21   2

print df2
   X  Y  Value  ID
0  2  5      7   1
1  3  6     34   2
```

```
#align dataframes
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.reindex_like(df1)
print df2
     X   Y  Value
ID               
0  NaN NaN    NaN
1    2   5      7
2    3   6     34
```

```
#create new df
df = df1.copy()
df['Value'] = df1['Value'].where(df1['Value'] > df2['Value'], df2['Value'])
#if value is NaN in column df2 give value of column1
df.loc[df2['Value'].isnull(), 'Value'] = df1['Value']
print df
    X  Y  Value
ID             
0   1  4     10
1   2  5     55
2   3  6     34
```

```
#sum columns Value to columns SUM 
df1['SUM'] = df1['Value'].sum()
df2['SUM'] = df2['Value'].sum()
print df1
    X  Y  Value  SUM
ID                  
0   1  4     10   86
1   2  5     55   86
2   3  6     21   86

#remove rows with NaN
print df2.dropna()
    X  Y  Value  SUM
ID                  
1   2  5      7   41
2   3  6     34   41
```